# Model field not displaying in Django Admin

Tags: django, heroku, django-models, django-admin

I have a Django project hosted on heroku

I added a new slug field to model

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

migrated it using south on heroku. Checked the heroku postgresDB as well for added field. All fine.

Opened Admin. No slug field showing...

added slug to fields[] in admin.py. Still not showing. Here is admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Category

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields    = ('name', 'slug')

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin).
```

I even did a heroku restart... No change. 
What can be done to show it ?

Comment: Not show in list page or edit page?

Comment: Name field is showing but not the slug field...

Comment: Come on, you already asked the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427068/django-model-field-not-showing-in-admin) yesterday.

Comment: I was downvoted for the reason i still dont know. Moreover i was just seeking an answer for my problem.

Comment: Does `readonly_fields = ['slug']` displays this field as read only?

Answer (score 10):

Try to use ***list_display*** like following:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Category

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields    = ('name', 'slug')

    #list of fields to display in django admin
    list_display = ['id', 'name', 'slug']


    #if you want django admin to show the search bar, just add this line
    search_fields = ['name', 'slug']

    #to define model data list ordering
    ordering = ('id','name')

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin).
```

Answer (score 2):

I see the solution in here Django Website: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#editable, use fields's editable property.

> editable
>
> Field.editable
>
> If False, the field will not be displayed in
> the admin or any other ModelForm. They are also skipped during model
> validation. Default is True.

I have posted a png image before, but I don't know how to display it.

[image: Django website]

Comment: Can you also add necessary information to answer? Links can broken/change in the future

Comment: `class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): readonly_fields=('first',) `
will show non editable (read only fields)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone ever faces this scenario

My admin classes were inheriting from `UserAdmin`, when they should have been inheriting from `admin.ModelAdmin`.

I had to change

```
class Model1(UserAdmin):
    ....
```

to

```
class Model1(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....
```